# Embedding of linear order into $\mathcal{P}(\omega)/\mathrm{fin}$

Tags: set-theory

I try to prove following problem (in Kunen):

> Assume $\mathrm{MA}(\kappa)$ and $(X,<)$ be a total order with $|X|\le\kappa$, then there are $a_x\subset \omega$ such that if $x<y$ then $x\subset^* y$.
>   ($x\subset^* y$ if $|x-y|<\omega$ and $|y-x|=\omega$.)
>
> *Hint*. Let $P$ be a set of pairs $(p,n)$, where $p$ is a partial function from $X$ to $\mathcal{P}(n)$ and the domain of $p$ is finite. 
>   Define $(p,n)\le (q,m)$ iff $\operatorname{dom}p\supseteq \operatorname{dom}q$, $n\ge m$, $p(x)\cap m=q(x)$ for each $x\in \operatorname{dom} q$ and
>   $$\forall x,y\in \operatorname{dom}q:x<y\implies p(x)-p(y)\subseteq m.$$
>   Use the $\Delta$-system lemma to prove that $(P,\le)$ has the c.c.c.

I prove $P$ has the c.c.c. and if $G$ is a filter which intersects the dense sets
$$D_x=\{(p,n):x\in\operatorname{dom}p\}$$
 over $P$ then $a_x:= \bigcup\{p(x)\mid\exists n<\omega: (p,n)\in G\text{ and }x\in\operatorname{dom}p\}$ satisfies $|a_x-a_y|<\omega$ if $x<y$. But I don't know how to prove $|a_y-a_x|=\omega$. I think some dense sets are added but which sets are added? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x<y$, $(q,m)\in P$, $x,y\in Dom(q)$, and $N<\omega$ define $p$ by $Dom(p)=Dom(q)$, $q(z)=p(z)$ if $z<y$, and $q(z)=p(z)\cup\{m+N\}$ otherwise, then $(p,m+N+1)\leq (q,m)$, and there is an element $\geq N$ in $q(y)\setminus q(x)$.

As all elements of $G$ are pairwise compatible, the genericity of this set and what we just showed implies $|a_y\setminus a_x|=\omega$

Comment: Sorry for late question, but I have a question. How to imply $|a_y-a_x|=\omega$ from genericity of $G$? I don't know how to make a detail of the proof.

Comment: @tetori What I did was to show that if $x,y\in Dom(q)$ for some $(q,m)\in G$, then for any $N<\omega$ the set of conditions $(p,n)$ such that $p(y)\setminus p(x)$ contains an element $\geq N$ is dense below $(q,m)$, the genericity of $G$ implies that $G$ intersects this set, so for any $N<\omega$ there is some $(p,m)\in G$ such that $p(y)\setminus p(x)$ contains an element $\geq N$, and thus $|a_y\setminus a_x|=\omega$

Answer (score 1):

For $x < y \in X$ and $N \in \omega$, consider the dense set $D_{x, y, N} = \{(p, n) \in P : x, y \in \text{dom}(p) \text{ and } (\exists m > n) (m \in p(x) - p(y))\}$.

Comment: I have two questions. At first, the sentence '$\exists m>n$' is a misspelling of $\exists m>N$'. Am I right? Second, I still don't know how to prove $|a_y-a_x|=\omega$. Would you give some explanation?